# Is it possible to inject my access token from a google site to my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, oauth-2.0

I have an app written in objc and when you open it up, you're presented with a view controller that has a google login button and when logged in you can access the page. Is there any way (since now that I've logged in before I have my access_token) to inject the access_token so that right when the app is launched it knows I am logged in? I know it doesn't make sense as to why I would do that but its necessary at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is acccess token in cookie?

Comment: @ABuckau Thanks for your reply! I don't believe so.

Comment: @ABuckau Do you know how to pass the access token in the nsuserdefault to a uiwebview?

Answer (score 1):

Save the access token to user defaults, and also save an expiration date.

When you launch, check the expiration date. If that date hasn't passed, use the access token to stay logged in.

If you need to keep the access token secure, save it to the keychain instead of of user defaults.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll have to try this! You wouldn't by chance have an example of those 4 steps would you? Adding access token to user defaults, saving an expiration, checking the expiration in viewDidLoad and granting access? Or possibly point me in the right direction of how to do those things? I really appreciate your time!

Comment: Do you know how to pass the access token in the nsuserdefault to a uiwebview?

Comment: It depends on how the web page is set up. Does it support an optional query string that lets you pass the access token as part of the URL? That's a very common way of doing it, but it depends on the site.

Comment: Here is a link to my new question if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it and seeing if you could help me figure this out. Thank you for your time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285161/is-it-possible-to-pass-the-access-token-as-part-of-the-url

Answer (score 1):

Building on Duncan C's answer, if your token is a string then something like this should do what you want:

```
NSString *token = @"xxxxx";
NSDate *sampleExpiration = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:10000];//expires in 10000 seconds from now

//save the token and expiration to NSUserDefaults
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"loginToken"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:sampleExpiration forKey:@"tokenExpiration"];

//retrieve the expiration, check it and then grab the token
NSDate *tokenExpiration = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"tokenExpiration"];
if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:tokenExpiration] < 0) {
    NSLog(@"token valid");

    //retrieve the token and use for login
    NSString *retrievedToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"loginToken"];
    NSLog(@"token is: %@", retrievedToken);
}
else {
    //prompt user to login again and repeat the process
}
```

Comment: Here is a link to my new question if you wouldn't mind taking a look at it and seeing if you could help me figure this out. Thank you for your time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285161/is-it-possible-to-pass-the-access-token-as-part-of-the-url

Comment: I will be home in a couple hours and will be happy to check it out then.